# When should we use the full Gabor Function and when do we use only the real part?

Tags: filters, filter-design, gabor

In this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-NZakhhB_Do), we see that the guy is only using the real part of the Gabor Filter to implement his project.

My questions are,

- When should we use the [complex Gabor Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabor_filter#Definition)?
- When should we use the real part of the Gabor Function?
- When should we use the imaginary part of the Gabor Function? Or, do we ever need it?

Answer (score 3):

The real part of the complex Gabor function is symmetric. This means it will give a large response at the centre of symmetric features such as lines.

The imaginary part of the complex Gabor function is anti-symmetric. This means it will give a large response at the centre of anti-symmetric features such as edges.

The real and imaginary parts are sort of in quadrature. This means when you take the magnitude of the response to the *complex* Gabor filter it will be high at the location of both edge and line features, which can be useful.

Comment: by "symmetric", do you mean *even* symmetry, $f(-x)=f(x)$?  and by "anti-symmetric", do you mean *odd* symmetry $f(-x)=-f(x)$?

Comment: Symmeyric with respect to the center of the Gabor wave function, which may or may not be at x=0.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson yep. When I use *even* and *odd* people tell me to use *symmetric* and *anti-symmetric* and vice versa  :)